# What does "FutureWarning: The behavior of rgb2gray will change in scikit-image 0.19" actually mean?

Tags: python, scikit-image

I am running a code, and I got this message:

> FutureWarning: The behavior of rgb2gray will change in scikit-image 0.19. Currently, rgb2gray allows 2D grayscale image to be passed as inputs and leaves them unmodified as outputs. Starting from version 0.19, 2D arrays will be treated as 1D images with 3 channels.

I do not understand the last sentence: "2D arrays will be treated as 1D images with 3 channels". Could you show by an example? And, won't that affect the mathematical operations I am doing on this array?

Answer (score 2):

I guess, calling [`skimage.color.rgb2gray`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/api/skimage.color.html#skimage.color.rgb2gray) on some 1D image should reveal, what's happening (in the future when inputting 2D images):

```py
from numpy import arange, uint8
from skimage.color import rgb2gray

# 2D input
gray = (252 + arange(2 ** 2))[::-1].astype(uint8).reshape((2, 2))
print(gray)
# [[255 254]
#  [253 252]]
print(rgb2gray(gray))
# [[255 254]
#  [253 252]]

# 1D input
gray = gray.flatten()
print(gray)
# [255 254 253 252]
print(rgb2gray(gray))
# 0.9966290196078431
print((0.2125 * gray[0] + 0.7154 * gray[1] + 0.0721 * gray[2]) / 255)
# 0.9966290196078431
```

Basically, the first three values of the (flattened) input will be assumed to be a single RGB tuple, and thus used to calculate the luminance of that (assumed) RGB tuple.

Whereas the first `rgb2gray` call gives the already stated warning

> FutureWarning: The behavior of rgb2gray will change in scikit-image 0.19. Currently, rgb2gray allows 2D grayscale image to be passed as inputs and leaves them unmodified as outputs. Starting from version 0.19, 2D arrays will be treated as 1D images with 3 channels.

the second `rgb2gray` call yields another warning:

> FutureWarning: Non RGB image conversion is now deprecated. For RGBA images, please use rgb2gray(rgba2rgb(rgb)) instead. In version 0.19, a ValueError will be raised if input image last dimension length is not 3.

So, it'll be interesting to see, how the handling of 2D images is exactly implemented – to prevent raising the `ValueError` mentioned in the second warning.

There are several discussions on the `skimage` GitHub issue tracker regarding backwards compatibility after applying the mentioned change in `rgb2gray`. Yes, you'll encounter differences, when you rely on the "old" output of `rgb2gray` when inputting some grayscale image.

```
----------------------------------------
System information
----------------------------------------
Platform:      Windows-10-10.0.16299-SP0
Python:        3.9.1
PyCharm:       2021.1.1
NumPy:         1.20.2
scikit-image:  0.18.1
----------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

While @HansHirse has answered the question in pretty good detail, I thought I would just add an example of feasible 2D array that the new `rgb2gray` method in `0.19` would likely expect and process:

```
A = [[r0, g0, b0],[r1, g1, b1],.....[rn, gn, bn]]
```

resulting in

```
A_gray=[l0, l1, ..., ln]
```

where `li = 0.2125 ri + 0.7154 gi + 0.0721 bi`