# scikit-image color.rgb2gray warning

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

Related to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67525612/what-does-futurewarning-the-behavior-of-rgb2gray-will-change-in-scikit-image-0) and this [discussion](https://github.com/scikit-image/scikit-image/issues/4915).

Unfortunately, my input images are in 2D grayscale.
Although my image processing script is still working fine, my IPython console is full of repeating warnings.
Can anyone help me:

1. how to turn off the warning or
2. how to solve it so that there is no more warning?

It is not clear how to do it (at least for a beginner like me).
Thanks!

version: scikit-image 0.17.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To turn off the warnings, you can add the following lines:

```py
import warnings
warnings.simplefilter(action='ignore', category=FutureWarning)
```

before you run the function in question.

Comment: Thank you. It's working. I didn't know about this library before. It's funny I have to import another library because of this. I hope there will be another answer for the item #2.